# Annotation values changed, but it is not being updated on the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I'm trying to plot a few points in Matplotlib in a scatterplot and show the coordinate values when hovering over the points. I'm passing the annotation as the argument to the callback, and when I try to update the values/text/etc. of the annotation within the callback function, the values change, but I see no changes on the plot. Am I missing something? I tried annotation.remove() but it's not working either (it's being removed but I still see it on the plot).

Here's the fragment of the code:

```
    annotation = plot_zoom.annotate('point offset from data', xy=(50, 93),
                      xycoords='data',
                      xytext=(-15, 25), textcoords='offset points',
                      arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
                      horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='bottom',
                      bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w")
                      )
    local_figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',
                                lambda event: on_plot_hover(event, plot_zoom, local_figure, annotation))

def on_plot_hover(event, plot, figure, annotation):
    if not event.dblclick:
       # do something
       print(annotation)
       annotation.set_text("IT HAS CHANGED")
       print(annotation)
```

And as the output I'm getting this:

```
Annotation(50, 93, 'point offset from data')
Annotation(50, 93, 'IT HAS CHANGED')
```

but on the plot I see no changes, I still see "point offset from data". What could be the reason for that?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a solution, so I'm posting it for anyone who might encounter this problem in the future. Once you're done with updating the annotation, you need to re-draw the canvas that the callback is connected to:

```
event.canvas.draw()
```